# Call JSON-functions on PostgreSQL 9.1

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I've got a query which works on PostgreSQL 9.3, due to the fact that it supports JSON types etc.

I would like to call this query on a remote API, which only runs PostgreSQL 9.1, with no such support.

These are the needed things:

```
ROW_TO_JSON, ARRAY_TO_JSON, ::json
```

Are is it somehow possible to rewrite a query to support such in PostgreSQL 9.1?

I have no control over the API and the remote database behind.

Comment: Other than writing your own functions or using someone else's, no.

Comment: You could write your own version in f.ex. `plpythonu`, but you have no control over the remote database ... XML can contain structured data, and it's supported in 9.1 http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-xml.html

Comment: Did you figure this out? I have a similar problem.